# Best way to write Custom Exception

Tags: java, exception

I am trying to write a custom exception with 3 constroctors. Can I initize final variables in 3 different constroctors? I am getting compilation errors. How to make this error free?

```
    public class CrifServiceFaultException extends RuntimeException {

        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public CrifServiceFaultException(String message) {  
// // - The blank final field errorDescription may not have been 
            super(message);
        }

        public CrifServiceFaultException(String processCode,
                String processDescription, String transformCode,
                String transformDescription) {  
// - The blank final field errorDescription may not have been 
     initialized
            super(processDescription + " " + transformDescription);
            this.processCode = processCode;
            this.processDescription = processDescription;
            this.transformCode = transformCode;
            this.transformDescription = transformDescription;
        }

        public CrifServiceFaultException(String errorCode, String errorDescription) {            // The blank final field transformDescription may not have been initialized

            super(errorDescription);
            setErrorCode(errorCode);
            setErrorDescription(errorDescription);
        }

        final private String processCode;
        final private String processDescription;
        final private String transformCode;
        final private String transformDescription;
        final private String errorCode;
        final private String errorDescription;
    // getters are here

    }
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add compilation errors you get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because, according to [Java specifications](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.2), **every** final variable must be initialized before the end of the constructor.

In your case in each constructor you leave some of them uninitialized (formally they're *blank*). In short you have to set a value for them (even when unused in a specific constructor):

```
public CrifServiceFaultException(String message)
{
    super(message);

    processCode = "";
    processDescription = "";
    transformCode= "";
    transformDescription= "";
    errorCode= "";
    errorDescription= "";
}

public CrifServiceFaultException(String processCode,
        String processDescription, String transformCode,
        String transformDescription)
{

    super(processDescription + " " + transformDescription);
    this.processCode = processCode;
    this.processDescription = processDescription;
    this.transformCode = transformCode;
    this.transformDescription = transformDescription;

    errorCode= "";
    errorDescription= "";
}

public CrifServiceFaultException(String errorCode, String errorDescription)
{
    super(errorDescription);
    setErrorCode(errorCode);
    setErrorDescription(errorDescription);

    processCode = "";
    processDescription = "";
    transformCode= "";
    transformDescription= "";
}
```

Note that even documentation says that:

> ...Declaring a variable final can serve as useful documentation...

From such sentence what we can guess is that `final` is only a *decoration* useful to avoid trivial mistakes at compile time (practically pretty similar to what `const` is in C++). Anyway IMO we shouldn't ever assume `final` variables are mutable (even through JNI) because they *may* enable strong optimizations at run-time (I'm thinking specifically about HotSpot): think about concurrent access and cache coherency (especially for primitive types).

Comment: It is sad that this is compiler only restriction. Final variables are normal variables during the runtime (which is nice for JNI though)

Comment: @Enerccio yes, even specs says _"...Declaring a variable final can serve as useful documentation..."_ even if in theory JVM may enable specific optimizations (especially in hotspot), honestly I don't know if it makes any difference at RT.